# Arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

While reading a book about JavaScript I stumbled across an example:

```
var names = new Array("Paul","Catherine","Steve");
var ages = new Array(31,29,34);
var concatArray;
concatArray = names.concat(ages);
```

My question is, why doesn't the variable `concatArray` need to be define as a `new Array()` in order to store the concatenated data for both arrays *name* and *ages* , but when I try to treat the `concatArray` as an array by adding another line of code "`document.write(concatArray[0])`", it works just like an array and shows me the data stored in the first element. I just wonder why I'm not declaring the `concatArray` as a new array, yet it still works as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Javascript is dynamically typed. A variable doesn't have a specifuc type, and an array is an object that you can assign to any variable.

When you declare a variable without assigning it a value, it just exists with an undefined value:

```
var answer;
// now the variable exists, but it doesn't have a value
answer = 42;
// now the variable has the numerical value 42
answer = "hello";
// now the numerical value has been replaced with the string value "hello"
answer = [];
// now the variable contains an empty array
answer[0] = 1337;
// now the variable contains an array that contains an item with the value 1337
answer = -1
// now the array is gone and the variable contains the value -1
```

Comment: but when i try to execute it in this way

<pre>
var myArray();
myArray[0] = 2; // or string or whatever

alert(myArray[0]);

</pre>


I did this by ignoring the line <b>var myArray = new Array();</b>,and the code doesnt works.Why?I thought javascript is a loosely typed language

Comment: @caramel: Declaring a variable like `var myArray();` is not valid. Javascript doesn't handle arrays that way, instead you create an array object and assign to a variable: `var myArray = new Array();` or `var myArray = [];`.

Comment: THANks for you guys guidance,i will read over it once again later and choose which is the best answer,THANKS again!!!

Answer (score 6):

You are declaring `concatArray` as a new array but the declaration is implicit.  The [`concat`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) function returns a new array which contains concatenated copies of the original two arrays.  The type of `concatArray` is inferred from the return type of the `concat` function.

Answer (score 3):

Variable don’t have a specific data type in Javascript like in other languages. You can assign a variable every value you want.

That means `var concatArray;` declares the variable but the value is `undefined`:

```
var concatArray;
alert(typeof concatArray === "undefined");
```

Only when assigning the return value of `names.concat(ages)` (an array) to `concatArray` it get’s that type:

```
var names = new Array("Paul","Catherine","Steve");
var ages = new Array(31,29,34);
var concatArray;
alert(typeof concatArray === "undefined");
concatArray = names.concat(ages);
alert(concatArray.constructor === Array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't care what the contents of the var are when it is declared; that is why you can declare `var concatArray` without needing to specify it as an array.  Once you assign it a value and a type (as the result of the `concat()` function) javascript treats the var as an array.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, w3schools says it pretty concisely:

> The concat() method is used to join two or more arrays.
>
> This method does not change the existing arrays, **it only returns a copy of the joined arrays.**

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)

Looks like Andrew and Matthew beat me to it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would make an answer slightly different of Andrew's one.
JavaScript variables are not strongly typed. You can put a string, then a number, then an object in the same variable. When you use the variable, the interpreter checks its current type is suitable for the usage you try to make. If you write:

```
var a = 45;
alert(a[0]);
a = [ 5 ];
alert(a[0]);
```

you will get successively *undefined* then *5*.